# Attempting to turn system config into an easier to compare format with awk or sed

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

1. Does anyone know what the term for this style of config is, where sub-sections are declared by tabs with an `exit` or `up` indicating the end of the section:

   ```
   config
       system
           security
               tacacs
                   server 1.1.1.1 port 88 
                   profile "default"
               exit
               user "one"
                   profile "admin" "reports"
                   password "E$OITGJ@vf2m92;l3j1"
                   home /home/one
               exit
           logs
               log 1
                   data foo
                   data bar
           exit
   ```
2. Is there a way with `awk`/`sed`/`tr`/whatever to declare the headers by looking for an end-of-section declaration that's on the same tab line (`exit` in this case), then insert the header in front of each line of that subsection, so that it would look more like this (quotes optional)?

   ```
   config system security tacacs server "1.1.1.1" port "88"
   config system security tacacs profile "default"  
   config system security user "one" profile "admin" "reports"
   config system security user "one" password "E$OITGJ@vf2m92;l3j1"
   config system security user "one" home "/home/one" 
   config system logs log "1" data "foo"
   config system logs log "1" data "bar"
   ```

The main problem is that the number of subsections and the names of various pieces are not static between different boxes/OS versions, so I might have 20 users or 50 logs with different settings for each and each subsection has further subsections with different default values or configuration flag names.

It seems like I should be able to do this with `awk` and `sed`, something like `/(^.*$)(\t\b.*$)*,(exit)/\1\s\2/`, but that's only getting me one line into the config.

Comment: The "line at a time" text processing tools (`bash`, `awk`, `sed`) aren't right for this task. Use a Programming language (`perl`, `python`, ...), which may come with a library to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The format is reminiscent of the [`mtree`](https://man.openbsd.org/mtree) configuration format (see [here](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/etc/mtree/4.4BSD.dist?rev=1.316&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) for an example of that).

The following `awk` program reformats the data into the new format that you mention.  It assumes that each section is indented a multiple of four spaces, but you should be able to change the `FS` variable from `" {4}"` to `"\t"` to use single tabs instead.

```c
BEGIN { FS = " {4}" }

$NF == "exit" { next }

NF > nf {
        section[++nf] = $NF
        next
}

function output() {
        $0 = ""
        for (i = 1; i <= nf; ++i)
                $i = section[i]
        print
}

{
        hold = $NF
        hold_nf = NF

        output()

        nf = hold_nf
        section[nf] = hold
}

END { output() }
```

The `nf` variable is the number of fields in the current section, meaning the number of "segments" to a configuration line.  The `section` array holds the current `nf` number of fields.

These are the blocks in the code:

- `BEGIN`: This block simply initializes the `FS` input field separator to an extended regular expression matching exactly four spaces.
- `$NF == "exit"`: This block skips lines that just says "exit".  It turns out we don't need these (a section ends by having smaller indentation than the previous one).
- `NF > nf`: This block increments `nf` and adds the data at the end of the current input line to the last field of our `section` array.  We call `next` at the end of the block to skip further processing of this line of input.
- `function output()`:  This is a function that output the current section when we call it.  We call it from the following two blocks.
- An unconditional block: If we get here, then the current section has to be outputted (the current section has ended, or is at least not further subsectioned).  We do this by calling our `output()` function.  Since we still have to pick up and store the data on this line of input, and since `output()` resets the current input record (`$0`), we save the data that we'd like to keep hold of in `hold`.  We do the same with the `NF` value, which may be lower than our `nf`.
- `END`: At the end of input, the last configuration section is yet to be outputted.  This in done here by calling `output()`.

Testing it on the data given in the question:

```
$ awk -f script file
config system security tacacs server 1.1.1.1 port 88
config system security tacacs profile "default"
config system security user "one" profile "admin" "reports"
config system security user "one" password "E$OITGJ@vf2m92;l3j1"
config system security user "one" home /home/one
config system logs log 1 data foo
config system logs log 1 data bar
```